# SLIC Superpixel number of superpixels is smaller than the requested

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, superpixels

When using the SLIC Superpixel segmentation, sometimes the resulting number of Superpixels is smaller than the requested, is this because of enforced connectivity, if not what is the reason behind this ?

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: Sci-kit image Python implementation

Comment: Kindly include your code and an example of an image that results in the problems you allude to.

Comment: You really need to include more information. Is it [this function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic)? It says “ n_segments: The (approximate) number of labels in the segmented output image.” Then why do you expect to get an exact number of segments?

Answer (score 0):

SLIC superpixel segmentation algorithm works by providing the corresponding superpixels based on the n_segments as indicated here  [Slic Algo](https://www.epfl.ch/labs/ivrl/research/slic-superpixels/)